# Transformer with a single turn plate as secondary

Tags: transformer

What kind of applications are transformers with a single turn secondary used for?
I believe a high current is generated, but couldn't really figure out a good practical example where this might be used.

Answer (score 5):

A Weller gun-style soldering iron is one good example.

[soldering gun http://static.emedco.com/media/catalog/product/Cooper-Hand-Tools-Wellerreg--Professional-Soldering-Guns-DD678-ba.jpg](http://static.emedco.com/media/catalog/product/Cooper-Hand-Tools-Wellerreg--Professional-Soldering-Guns-DD678-ba.jpg)

Also, pretty much any spot-welder for sheet metal.

[image: spot welder]
<sub>(source: [harborfreight.com](http://www.harborfreight.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/i/m/image_11330.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 3):

I've used a single turn secondary with the wires passing through a current transformer for testing it at hundreds of amps. The primary was fed from a variac so I could control current fed through the CT. Checking linearity was the objective.

Rf transformers are quite commonly made with one or a few turns to make them work effectively at VHF and UHF.

I've also made data coupling transformers where one winding was on a rotating spindle. Single turns had to be used because the data rate was so high ie tens of Mbps.

Same sort of idea for transmitting power across a small gap on rotating apparatus. Single turns were used and resonated with tuning capacitors.

Answer (score 1):

I saw one in a 12V 800W server power supply (Ablecom PWS-801-1R).

In case you were wondering - the PSU provides 12V and 5VSB, the other voltages are generated by the backplane.